# SQL Get past twelve months of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Just realized my SQL command wasn't working properly.

Basically I have one table with two columns. It keeps track of the user count for each month.
The layout is like this:

```
StatDate    UserCount
--------    ---------
11/2/2012       5
12/8/2012      10
12/23/2012     25
1/8/2013       50
2/18/2013      100
3/22/2013      33
```

and so on. You can see there can be multiple entries per month. I need to be able to retrieve the latest value for each month for the past year so I can put it in a line graph.

I was doing this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 UserCount FROM Stats_UserCount WHERE MONTH(StatDate)=MONTH(GetDate()) - 0 ORDER BY StatDate DESC;
SELECT TOP 1 UserCount FROM Stats_UserCount WHERE MONTH(StatDate)=MONTH(GetDate()) - 1 ORDER BY StatDate DESC;
SELECT TOP 1 UserCount FROM Stats_UserCount WHERE MONTH(StatDate)=MONTH(GetDate()) - 2 ORDER BY StatDate DESC;
SELECT TOP 1 UserCount FROM Stats_UserCount WHERE MONTH(StatDate)=MONTH(GetDate()) - 3 ORDER BY StatDate DESC;
SELECT TOP 1 UserCount FROM Stats_UserCount WHERE MONTH(StatDate)=MONTH(GetDate()) - 4 ORDER BY StatDate DESC;
SELECT TOP 1 UserCount FROM Stats_UserCount WHERE MONTH(StatDate)=MONTH(GetDate()) - 5 ORDER BY StatDate DESC;
SELECT TOP 1 UserCount FROM Stats_UserCount WHERE MONTH(StatDate)=MONTH(GetDate()) - 6 ORDER BY StatDate DESC;
SELECT TOP 1 UserCount FROM Stats_UserCount WHERE MONTH(StatDate)=MONTH(GetDate()) - 7 ORDER BY StatDate DESC;
SELECT TOP 1 UserCount FROM Stats_UserCount WHERE MONTH(StatDate)=MONTH(GetDate()) - 8 ORDER BY StatDate DESC;
SELECT TOP 1 UserCount FROM Stats_UserCount WHERE MONTH(StatDate)=MONTH(GetDate()) - 9 ORDER BY StatDate DESC;
SELECT TOP 1 UserCount FROM Stats_UserCount WHERE MONTH(StatDate)=MONTH(GetDate()) - 10 ORDER BY StatDate DESC;
SELECT TOP 1 UserCount FROM Stats_UserCount WHERE MONTH(StatDate)=MONTH(GetDate()) - 11 ORDER BY StatDate DESC;
```

But you can see the problem comes in when the MONTH is a negative number because it doesn't know how to go to the previous year. Is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: Date handling differs on different DBMSs. Which are you using? SQLite? MySQL? Microsoft SQL server?

Comment: @CharlesBurns It has the `TOP` keyword, so it's probably MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Assuming you're using SQL Server*.

You can get past 12 months by comparing StatDate with first number of current month of previous year :) `StatDate >= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()) - 12, 0);` (and this type of query also will use indexes on StatDate column if you have any). And you can use `row_number()` function to get data you need in one query:

```
with cte as (  
    select
        StatDate, UserCount,
        row_number() over(partition by month(StartDate) order by StartDate desc) as rn
    from Table1
    where StatDate >= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()) - 12, 0)
)
select StatDate, UserCount
from Table1
where rn = 1
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4a63/4)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

Use derived table to get latest date of each month in last one year and then do an inner join with original table to get the required count on those dates as:

```
SELECT UserCount, T.STATDATE
FROM 
    (SELECT MAX(StatDate) AS STATDATE
     FROM STATS_USERCOUNT
     WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH,GETDATE(),StatDate) <=12
     GROUP BY MONTH(StatDate)) AS T
INNER JOIN STATS_USERCOUNT S ON T.STATDATE = S.StatDate ;
```